# Extract Data from CLOB column with 0 value in oracle to postgresql using ora2pg Tool

Tags: oracle, postgresql, database-migration, ora2pg

i'm facing a problem by the migration of oracle 11 & 19c to postgresql 11 database using ora2pg Tool.
wenn i export clob data type with 0 value using ora2pg i get Null value instead of 0 in postgresql.

I treid to set the parameters EMPTY_LOB_NULL and NULL_EQUAL_EMPTY in config file to 1. But i still get the same result.

Can anyone help me?!!
thank you in advance

Comment: what do you mean clob with 0 value ? you mean clob length ??

Comment: no i mean CLOB value = 0